# Getting the same validation metrics on Keras neural network every epoch, but only sometimes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

So I have a simple regression problem that I'm trying to solve with a Keras neural network. The model is quite simple, but works relatively well *sometimes*.. Problem example: I run the model creation and training code for the first time and everything works fine. Then, I re-run all of this and suddenly the validation loss is the same every epoch and doesn't get any lower. (also, in cases like this, the regular loss is way too high) If I run it again after that, it could be all normal and well again.

The problem seems to only appear when using the Adam optimizer. I haven't encountered this problem yet with the Adadelta optimizer.

It's not a consistent problem, which makes it quite difficult to debug.
I'm assuming that it's either some kind of random variable initialization in the model, or a wrong output activation function.

I've tried playing around with settings within the Adam optimizer like the learning rate, decay, etc. Also I played with the batch size during training, but nothing seems to 100% solve this problem.

Here is some simple code which I use for creating and training the model.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(80, input_dim=X.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(80, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')
])
opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=['mean_absolute_error'], metrics=[rmse])

history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, batch_size=20, validation_data=[X_test, y_test], shuffle=True)
```

And here is a small sample of the data that I'm using to train the model (sorry for the bad formatting):

```
vendor_id   passenger_count pickup_longitude    pickup_latitude dropoff_longitude   dropoff_latitude    distance_haversine  distance_dummy_manhattan    direction   pickup_cluster  dropoff_cluster Month   DayofMonth  Hour    dayofweek
2   1   -74.003440  40.743584   -73.98218   40.737580   1.911775    2.458974    110.433360  55  25  1   29  0   4
2   3   -74.002650  40.733400   -73.96405   40.773510   5.519362    7.712331    36.076637   22  5   5   5   14  3
1   1   -73.980380  40.732445   -73.97107   40.754932   2.620580    3.284788    17.408050   88  24  3   8   7   1
```

So, currently I sometimes get the following output. However, I expect the output of the model training to **always** be something like this, not just sometimes..

```
Epoch 1/50
72816/72816 [==============================] - 17s 240us/sample - loss: 274.6910 - rmse: 370.7113 - val_loss: 248.2299 - val_rmse: 351.9400
Epoch 2/50
72816/72816 [==============================] - 17s 227us/sample - loss: 241.0651 - rmse: 334.2888 - val_loss: 235.2585 - val_rmse: 327.8128
Epoch 3/50
72816/72816 [==============================] - 15s 204us/sample - loss: 232.9749 - rmse: 321.4998 - val_loss: 230.2952 - val_rmse: 319.8226
```

Sometimes, the output that I get looks like this:

```
Epoch 1/50
72816/72816 [==============================] - 16s 220us/sample - loss: 759.9131 - rmse: 894.2183 - val_loss: 759.6450 - val_rmse: 895.1505
Epoch 2/50
72816/72816 [==============================] - 15s 206us/sample - loss: 759.9131 - rmse: 894.3421 - val_loss: 759.6450 - val_rmse: 894.2359
Epoch 3/50
72816/72816 [==============================] - 14s 195us/sample - loss: 759.9131 - rmse: 894.6163 - val_loss: 759.6450 - val_rmse: 894.1488
```

Is there any explanation for this, or am I doing something terribly wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: If you want a normal initializer, go for `glorot_normal`! :)

Comment: Also, since output from ReLU activations aren't zero-centered, it's typically beneficial to follow such layers with batch normalization (e.g. `layers.BatchNormalization()`).

Comment: I've changed all the `kernel_initializer`'s to `glorot_normal`, and I added a `BatchNormalization` layer after every ReLU activated layer. The model trains more slowly than before now, but I haven't encountered the original issue yet. Thanks! Any idea why it takes more epochs for my model to learn now?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, there's a relationship between the size of the network and the training-time benefit of batch normalization. For a network as small as yours, perhaps I ought not have mentioned it. You might crank up the learning rate a bit to compensate. I suspect it's what's resolving the original issue; at some point during training, some weights probably resulted in important features falling dramatically askew in the linear section of the activation function.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know your model might be learning nothing. Indeed, your loss function gives too high output values (it might be around 1 or less but you have 240).

Do you have a data preprocessing step before your training step ?

Comment: I do have some simple data preprocessing, but the output variable is not preprocessed in any way. It's just the raw amount of seconds (duration of action), but that doesn't seem to be a problem since sometimes the model just learns and the loss gets lower and lower every epoch. (I'll edit my question and add a sample of my data)